# I need to connect value of my hash in my web page

Tags: perl

I made a cgi form and in this a hash is inserted to see the output. The logic is when user enters his name he will get sequence of DNA related to his name. I am trying to get values from anonymous array of the hash.

I have done 2 parts of this program and stuck with the last one.
If the input is valid, turn the string into uppercase, and then use the hash  to produce the appropriate DNA sequence and output as:

1.Take one letter of the user's name at a time, and use hash created in step 1 to look up that letter and get a corresponding DNA codon.

1. Build a 'DNA' sequence made up of these triplets, and when finished, display it to the user. 
   3.For most letters there will be more than one triplet that will match a letter of their name. In this case I have to find out how many choices there are and using a random number generator to choose one. Therefore if the user enters their name multiple times they will get different output.

   print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

   ```
       if (!param){
           #if no data, display blank form
           print headingstuff("");
           print programInfo();
           print form();
           print endingstuff();    
       }else{
           print headingstuff("");
           print programInfo();

           #validate user name
           my $name = param("name");    


           my $nameLength = length($name);       

           if($nameLength == 0){
               print form(param("name"));
               print "<br>Please enter a vaild name!! <br>"; 
           }else{       



       my %hash = (
                   "A"=>["Alanine","Ala",["GCT"," GCC"," GCA"," GCG"]],
                   "R"=>["Arginine","Arg",["CGT"," CGC"," CGA"," CGG"," AGA"," AGG"]],
                   "N"=>["Asparagine","Asn",["AAT"," AAC"]],
                   "D"=>["Aspartic acid","Asp",["GAT"," GAC"]],
                   "C"=>["Cysteine","Cys",["TGT"," TGC"]],
                   "E"=>["Glutamic acid","Glu",["GAA"," GAG"]],
                   "Q"=>["Glutamine","Gln",["CAA"," CAG"]],
                   "G"=>["Glycine","Gly",["GGT"," GGC"," GGA"," GGG"]],
                   "H"=>["Histidine","His",["CAT"," CAC"]],
                   "I"=>["Isoleucine","Ile",["ATT"," ATC"," ATA"]],
                   "L"=>["Leucine","Leu",["TTA"," TTG"," CTT"," CTC"," CTA"," CTG"]],
                   "K"=>["Lysine","Lys",["AAA"," AAG"]],

                   );  


                   print "<br>Codons for user name: <br>";
                 my @nameAsArray = split('', $name);

               foreach my $letter(@nameAsArray){
                   my $uLetter = uc($letter);                    
                   my @val = @{$hash{$uLetter}};
                   my $letterDna = getRandomDNA(\@{$val[2]});              
                   print "<br>";

               }            




           sub linkToOriginalPage{
               return <<L;
               <br><br>
               <a href="xyz.cgi">Click here to return to original page.</a>
               <br><br>
           L
           }

           sub headingstuff {
               my $mytitle = $_[0];
               return <<H;
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
           <!DOCTYPE html>
           <html>
               <head>
                   <title>$mytitle</title>
               </head>
               <body>
                   <h1>  :) </h1>
           H
           }
           ######################################################
           sub endingstuff{
               return <<E;
               </body>
           </html>
           E
           }
           ####################################################

           sub form{
               return <<F;
               <form method="post" action="xyz" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <table>
                       <tr>
                           <td>Enter your name:</td> 
                           <td> <input type="text" name="name" value="$_[0]"/></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td colspan="2"><input type="submit"/></td>
                       </tr>
                    </table>
               </form>
           F
           }
   ```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what isn't working? Your description about what should happen is rather lengthy, but I don't see anything about the actual problem is.

Comment: I am not able to understand how I code further to get my value of codon (ACGTGGATC)which is an anonymous array to $name so that I can see it on my web page.

Comment: OK, you've explained how to convert a name to a DNA sequence, depending on its letters. However you seem also to want to convert a name to a "codon" depending on its _length_. Can you explain how that conversion happens?

Comment: Are the elements in each subarray the codons for the letter in its parent array? (You've not defined what a "codon" is in this context).

Comment: Presumably "ACGTCGTGACTG" is not a good codon example for "HAI", since it would need four letters as input, rather than three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understood correctly, what you want is to display the `%hash`? :

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

if (!param){
    #if no data, display blank form
    print headingstuff("");
    print programInfo();
    print form();
    print endingstuff();    
}else{
    print headingstuff("");
    print programInfo();

    #validate user name
    my $name = param("name");



    my $nameLength = length($name);       

    if($nameLength == 0){
        print form(param("name"));
        print "<br>Please enter a vaild name!! <br>"; 
    }else{
     my array_name = "", $name;



    my %hash = (
                "A"=>["Alanine","Ala",["GCT"," GCC"," GCA"," GCG"]],
                "R"=>["Arginine","Arg",["CGT"," CGC"," CGA"," CGG"," AGA"," AGG"]],
                "N"=>["Asparagine","Asn",["AAT"," AAC"]],
                "D"=>["Aspartic acid","Asp",["GAT"," GAC"]],
                "C"=>["Cysteine","Cys",["TGT"," TGC"]],
                "E"=>["Glutamic acid","Glu",["GAA"," GAG"]],
                "Q"=>["Glutamine","Gln",["CAA"," CAG"]],
                "G"=>["Glycine","Gly",["GGT"," GGC"," GGA"," GGG"]],
                "H"=>["Histidine","His",["CAT"," CAC"]],
                "I"=>["Isoleucine","Ile",["ATT"," ATC"," ATA"]],
                "L"=>["Leucine","Leu",["TTA"," TTG"," CTT"," CTC"," CTA"," CTG"]],
                "K"=>["Lysine","Lys",["AAA"," AAG"]],

                );  


                print "<br>Codons for user name: <br>";

        # hash display
        foreach my $key ( keys %hash ){
            print "$key : <br>";
            foreach my $elem ( @{ $hash{$key} } ) {
                print "$elem " if ref $elem ne 'ARRAY';
                next if ref $elem ne 'ARRAY';
                print "<br/> @{ $hash{$key} } ";
            }
        }
                print "<br>";

            }





        sub linkToOriginalPage{
            return <<L;
            <br><br>
            <a href="xyz.cgi">Click here to return to original page.</a>
            <br><br>
        L
        }

        sub headingstuff {
            my $mytitle = $_[0];
            return <<H;
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>$mytitle</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>  :) </h1>
        H
        }
        ######################################################
        sub endingstuff{
            return <<E;
            </body>
        </html>
        E
        }
        ####################################################

        sub form{
            return <<F;
            <form method="post" action="xyz" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                 <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Enter your name:</td> 
                        <td> <input type="text" name="name" value="$_[0]"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit"/></td>
                    </tr>
                 </table>
            </form>
        F
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Tudor I am getting output in web but not what exactly I am working for.I want  to extract only sequence  part of hash randomly.("GCT"," GCC"," GCA"," GCG")  etc when an alphabet is entered in web form not Alanine","Ala (names 2 or 3 value of hash).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the missing piece you seek is `getRandomDNA`, specifically how to get a random item from an array.

You can use `rand $x` to get a random float from 0 to `$x`, so to get a random item in an array `@array`, do:

```
$item = $array[int rand @array];
```

Since you're already passing the function that contains all the DNA sequences and nothing else, fitting it together should be straightforward.